# showing table twice in partial rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, view, associations, partials

Newbie to rails, I think i might be overlooking something very simple here, but I am displaying a table twice in a partial, not sure if it's to do with my associations.

Here is the **Properties controller**:

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter 

  def index
    @property= Property.all
  end

  def new
    @property = current_user.property.build if signed_in? 
  end

  def show
    @property = current_user.property.paginate( params[:page])
  end
```

Here is the **Users Controllers**:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    authorize! :index, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @property = @user.property.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

Here are the associations in the models:
**user model**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :property, dependent: :destroy
```

**property**:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :name
  belongs_to :user
```

Here is the `_property.html.erb` partial

```
<li>
  <table>                         
    <tr>                          
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>address</th>
    </tr>
    <% @user.property.each do |property| %> 
    <tr>
      <td><%= property.name %></td>  
      <td><%= property.address %></td> 
    </tr>
    <% end %>                        
  </table>
</li>
```

Here is the `show.html.erb`

```
<div class="row">
   <aside class="span4">
      <section>
         <h1>
           My Properties 
         </h1>
      </section>
   </aside>

   <div class="span8">
     <% if @user.property.any? %>
       <h3>Properties (<%= @user.property.count %>)</h3>
         <ol>
           <%= render @property %>
         </ol>
         <%= will_paginate @property %>
     <% end %>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is what is rendered in the browser. https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYgHS.png

Let me know if there is anything else will be of help with this question. All responses appreciated.

Comment: In your User model you should have `has_many :properties` instead of `has_many :property`.

Comment: The second part of your "SQL log" looks like it's just showing a console interaction. Was there something else you were intending to show?

Comment: Tried to edit the question with an image won't allow me to due to <10 reps. Here is what is rendered in the browser anyway http://i.imgur.com/SlilDo3.png

Comment: changed to property to properties, still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you do `@property =  Property.all` you are setting up a collection of instances of the `Property` class... there's clearly more than on in this collection.

When you use

```
render @property
```

it will render the _property template for every item in the collection called `@property`
Even if, inside the _property template you then use `user.property.each` - then that means that you're effectively saying:

> for each property in @property, render the template _property... and
>   each time you do that, render a new table that does a table row for
>   each property in user.property.

if you want only one table, and only each row to be rendered per individual "property" in the list of properties that is called `@property` then you need to pull the table outside of the render.

eg:

```
   <h3>Properties (<%= @user.property.count %>)</h3>
       <table>                         
       <tr>                          
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>address</th>
       </tr>
       <%= render @property %>
       </table>
```

and _property:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= property.name %></td>  
  <td><%= property.address %></td> 
</tr>
```